# Show A table only if it has some rows to show

Tags: html, ajax, asp-classic

I need to create a table which should be shown in the page only if it has some content (rows) inside it. The purpose of the table would primarily be to display the data (excel sheets) imported by the user. I am doing all the coding in ASP, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: what's your markup of an empty table? just `<table></table>` ? why don't you simply print the table if there is some content to put inside?

Comment: yes, the markup is <table> </table>. Sorry, i couldn't understand the latter part of your comment.

Comment: Note on quality of the question: Please consider posting code samples (i.e. "I'm doing it now with following code") that shows what you are trying to achieve and problem you have. Code sample also would clarify your server language as it is rare to see new code written in asp-classic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can keep your table `hidden` and on page load you can check if `table` has rows inside it, like

**HTML**

```
<table id="xldata" style="display:none">
<thead>
  <th>Colimn One</th><th>Colimn Two</th>
</thead>
<tbody>    
  <tr><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
<tbody>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    if($('table#xlData tbody').children().size()) $('table#xlData').show();
});
```

But you should use an `id` for the table, i.e. `id="xldata"`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ibaceb/5/edit).